# What are necessary components and strategies for developing a REST-based client program?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, web-development-server, apiclient

I have been doing research for days and am so lost because everyone implements this differently or these tutorials are unclear.

I will be writing a web application that uses API's from sites like AWS, CROWD, etc. to create a single-sign on portal to manage many different things.

I have never worked in web development before, so this is all new. How should I get started in this project? What exact files will I need to create? Any advice would be helpful.

The only constraints that I have been given is that this will run in Tomcat, so I need to use java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the basics of client - server architecture and develop a 
web service to standardize the REST based actions such as RPC.